# RNN on sequences made out of feature vectors of two different lengths

Tags: lstm

I have a sequential dataset comprised out of two different kinds of events (say, A and B events) for which the feature vectors have different sizes, i.e. all A events are described with *a*-dimensional feature vectors while all B events are described with *b*-dimensional features vectors, a != b.

Note that this is not about variable sized sequences (though that can be the case here as well), instead it is about having *sequences made out of variable sized vectors*.

My question is how do I set up an RNN (LSTM) in keras in order to learn from such sequences?

I don't want to reduce this into training two different RNNs on A and B events separately, because I need to maintain the sequential nature of events {A1, A2, B1, A3, B2, ...}.

It is as if I need an RNN model with a conditional input shape, being (None, a) if x belongs to A and (None, b) otherwise.

I wonder if *backend.switch* or likes of it can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in the following way:

I started with replicating the original sequence into two sequences where in each of them I replaced events of the other type with zero vectors whose length is same as those of the events retained in that sequence, hence all time steps had the same feature vector length. I also computed the mask for each sequence.

I then applied TimeDistributed dense layers on each sequence separately with the same output length *c*, and multiplied the output of each dense by the corresponding mask.

Finally, I added up (element-wise) two sequences into one.
This resulted in a restored homogeneous version of the original heterogenous sequence in the common space, c, which I could then feed into an LSTM layer.